# microwaving scrambled eggs

Tags: eggs, microwave

Has anyone come up with a way to cook beaten eggs via microwave?

My attempts to do so have resulted in a off-coloured mess with the consistency of rubber.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/why-does-my-omelet-with-velveeta-froth-up-in-the-microwave

Comment: Note : any cooking times for microwaves should be treated with suspicion, as you don't know if the person posting has a 800 Watt or 1200 Watt microwave.  You may also want to adjust the power setting so you're cooking at lower power to avoid rubbery eggs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microwave scrambled eggs will never be like real scrambled eggs.

That said, I've obtained decent results when only a microwave is available by beating the eggs first, microwaving for 30 seconds, stirring, and then microwaving in 10 second bursts, stirring after each one until desired doneness is achieved.

If you are just looking for ways to cook eggs in the microwave, and you don't care about the style, try doing a microwave poached egg:
Put 1/3c of water in a mug. Crack an egg into the water. Stab the yolk with a fork/toothpick/etc (shouldn't break the yolk, just pierce it. This is so that it won't explode, which apparently is a risk, although I've never had it happen, personally.) Microwave for about a minute, remove egg with slotted spoon. Adjust timing up/down 5 seconds, depending on your microwave and how you like your egg (e.g. I like mine kind of runny: in one microwave I use, that's 55 seconds, in another it's 1min even.)

Comment: Agree with your microwave scrambled eggs technique.  To make them creamier and less rubbery, try adding a splash of milk or cream to the initial mixture as well.  Stirring after each microwave burst is essential too!

Answer (score 2):

Microwaved Scrambled Eggs are totally doable; they're quick, easy, and satisfying.

The trick is not to expect to just need to scramble the eggs once, just after the eggs are cracked.  They need to be scrambled two or three more times, as they cook; just because the edges of a bowl cook before the center; kinda like the eggs on the bottom of a pan cook first when not cooking an omelet style egg.

Seasoning is another matter..I think when you fry scrambled eggs the browning that occurs ads a significant amount of taste; that isn't there when microwaving.  Adding cheese, meat, or families of herbs helps.  But I'm still trying to figure out a way to spice eggs, that is actually as easy as the microwave...

Answer (score 1):

The bagel shop near my work microwaves their eggs for their egg sandwich (caveat: they may be some kind of egg beaters or other substitute). They put about 1/2 cup of the liquid in a microwaveable dish, nuke for 2 minutes. They check about 3/4 of the way to make sure that the bottom is cooking; if not they flip the egg puck.

The trick may simply be to use an egg substitute instead of real eggs.

Comment: I think real eggs would work fine. I think the trick is that they are making an egg puck, not scrambled eggs. That's actually one of the few good uses for microwaved "scrambled" eggs -- sandwich filling.

Comment: @TJ yeah, I'm sure you're right that real eggs would work; I was close to asking the purpose of the scrambled eggs - i.e. as a standalone or as a 'filling'.

Answer (score 1):

> My attempts to do so have resulted in a off-coloured mess with the consistency of rubber.

Absolutely. Exceedingly high heat gives eggs a ruber texture. And this is because the microwave oven heats the outside **too** quickly before it can heat the inside. I just don't think cooking any eggs in the microwave will ever work well unless you can somehow distribute the heat evenly and slowly (so that it never peaks in anyway part, else you will get rubbery eggs), and that is something microwaves fail on both parts.

Answer (score 1):

Microwaving scrambled eggs is quick, easy, fuss free and requires very little washing up!I have been doing it for years, both in my kitchen at home and at work (I have a cafe).

- Use only very fresh eggs
- Add 15% milk to your egg mix
- Whisk well and heat on high for 1 min
- Whisk again and heat on high for 30 secs
- Continue to do this in 30 second bursts until light and fluffy.
- Season and then serve.

I think where a lot of people go wrong is they season the eggs before the cooking process, this is what leads to "rubbery eggs". Don't season until your ready to serve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. The efficiency of a microwave in heating up substances with a high proportion of water means that the egg nearest to the microwaves (the outside of the bowl) over cooks while the inside is still raw. I have tried doing it by stirring every 15 seconds, but it takes longer - and gives a poorer result - than just beating eggs with a splash of milk and stirring them continuously over a lowish heat in a pan.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine but you need "too the second" timing, a few seconds over and they go rubbery and grey

Weigh your eggs (and milk), and record the times taken, so you can build a chart for future reference for your microwave oven

Remember they continue to cook after you take them out, so you can pull them out a bit early

Add a little baking powder 1/8 to 1/4 tsp to get a better fluff without constant stirring