# omelettes and scrambled eggs - How long can I store them?

Tags: eggs, storage-lifetime, scrambled-eggs, omelette

Is it a good idea to keep make a lot of them and keep them in the refrigerator? I like them for breakfast but I don't like cooking every morning. For how long I can keep them?

Comment: If you're looking for time savings in cooking scrambled eggs, you'd almost be better going with [microwaving them](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12237/microwaving-scrambled-eggs), as you'd likely want to warm the previously cooked eggs anyway.  Another slight time savings is to do what my grandfather referred to as 'silver and gold' eggs -- break 'em directly into the warm pan, and then scramble them.

Comment: @Joe: I have always just added the eggs directly into the pan, but that was in order to have one less dish to clean.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What Tim said. Eggs just don't hold very well, and they are very sensitive to temperature--reheating them basically will mean re-cooking them. I would never store eggs in this manner, because the texture and flavour degradation will make them unpleasant to eat.

However, to actually answer your question--and again, I urge you not to do this because stored and reheated eggs will taste like garbage--cooked eggs should keep for up to 72 hours in the refrigerator. Remember to chill them as rapidly as possible after cooking, and you may wish to undercook slightly in order to minimize problems when reheating.

I would use 72 hours as an absolute maximum, particularly if you are undercooking. 48 hours is probably wiser.

Answer (score 10):

So I was thinking about this, and realized that there are plenty of egg dishes that work well out of the refrigerator, but the thing is, you don't reheat them, you serve them at room temperature:

- quiche
- fritatta
- pizza rustica
- tortilla (the spanish dish, not the south american item of the same name)

I mean, it's not going to be the exact same as making it fresh and serving it warm, but the problem is in reheating eggs when you tend to overcook it.  (I once turned a pizza rustica into a nasty puddle of water when I tried reheating it)

So, my thought on the matter is you could probably pull it off, just don't heat it.  You *might* be able to microwave it on really low heat to just take the chill off ... but don't try to get it hot.

You'd have to try it yourself to see if it's an acceptable taste / texture / temperature for your palette.  You might also consider either serving it with something else warmed through to let some of the heat transfer (eg, place it on a freshly toasted bagel or english muffin)

Answer (score 7):

When it comes to taste, eggs are very difficult to preserve. When they are warmed after refrigeration they cook further, and fried eggs have a narrow window in which they taste great.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how long they remain sanitary but when I'm cooking scrambled eggs for a lot of people and I have to store them in the oven to keep warm I always cover them with slices of cheese. This seems to help keep their flavor as if they were right off the pan and prevents the surfaces of the eggs from drying out and becoming crusty. It may improve their refrigeration life as well?

Answer (score 2):

I have been scrambling three large eggs at a time. I eat one and put the rest in the fridge in a sealed plastic container. I make egg salad out of the leftovers for sandwiches over the next two days adding various things like onion bits, dill, mustard, hot sauce, lemon pepper, cheese slices, etc. The eggs taste just fine. The sealed container keeps them moist.

Comment: You make egg salad out of scrambled eggs? I've never tried this before. I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Interesting.  I know I've had potato salad made with mashed potatoes that was amazing, and this sounds like a similar variation.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping cooked eggs is not very tasty

Follow my previous [post on "better-scrambled-eggs"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7405/better-scrambled-eggs/8973#8973) for making scrambled eggs in 60 seconds from eggs to plate (thin stainless skillet on a gas stove)

Answer (score 0):

I've been cooking my eggs in a small round pan. To keep that shape, I'll cook 4 batches for 4 days at a time, then place them in fridge. Wake up, grab one round cooked egg, nuke in the microwave for 30 secs and it tastes great to me on a piece of Ezekiel bread.  I have 3 small children and a busy morning, so I need something healthy and fast with no mess in the morning.

Comment: so, what is your answer? "They are good for at least 4 days"? I am not sure what exactly you are trying to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Eggs keep fine for two weeks just fine raw in the shell and about abit over a week cooked into a fritta shape, 25 sec in a microwave works wonders

Answer (score -2):

What about freezing the eggs in separate containers? Daily portions, thaw one the night before and cook it in the morning. Microwave if you have it.  Would this work?

Comment: Eggs don't like being frozen. The yolks change too much when defrosted. And besides, you want to start an omelette with as warm an egg as possible, because then it curdles less.

Answer (score -3):

I've heard Sanitary wise they are good for a week, but my experience is after about 3-4 days they tend to give you the runs, soo I wouldn't make more than enough for 3 or 4 days.